# How do I apply different merge drivers for different branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I have the following in my .git/config:

```
[merge "customDriver"]
    name = A custom merge driver
    driver = ./mergepom %O %A %B %L %P
    recursive = text
```

Where mergepom is a bashscript. In .gitattributes i have defined `temp.txt merge=customDriver`.

This executes perfectly fine, and the bash script gets executed.

However, I would like to define different merging strategies for different branches. E.g. if I merge from `feature/branch1` into `staging` I want a certain strategy, but if I merge from `staging` into `feature/branch1` I want another.

Is it possible to pass the source and target branches into the driver script somehow? I can always get the branch I'm standing in using `git branch` but that doesn't seem very reliable.

Also, during the driver execution, there seems to be no `.git/MERGE_HEAD` file yet, so it seems that I'm not in an actual merge state at this stage.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

Comment: `.gitattributes` is Git-controlled.  Put different versions into different commits, and when those commits are current, you'll have the commit-specific (which can thus be branch-specific) version in place. Doing a merge at that point will use the one that is in place at that point. (If that's unweildy—having customdriverA, customdriverB, etc—you can indeed query the current branch, but use `git symbolic-ref` to do so, not `git branch`.)

Comment: Of course, that gets you only the "merge into" branch, not the "merge from" commit. There seems to be no way to find the "merge from" commit ID directly. (Note, Git does not actually merge from a *branch*: the argument to `git merge` is a *commit specifier*.  The only special thing giving a branch *name* does is set up the merge message.  Using `$(git rev-parse otherbranch)` produces the same merge result.)  Last, note that you may not be on *any* branch when you run `git merge` since you may be in "detached HEAD" mode.

Comment: Thanks, this is the route I went with.